# How can we remove unused bss symbol?

Tags: c, gcc, ld, elf

As we know, we can use "-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections" and "-Wl, --gc-sections" to remove unused code and data. But how to remove unused bss symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say that global variables initialized with 0 "are" in the bss, actually the variable does not exist in the binary.

When your program starts to run, it will reserve a section in RAM and fill this section with zeros. Places in your program that access a variable in bss will point to this section.

Variables in bss do not occupy space in the binary image.

The difference between the bss and the data is just that as we know some values are zeros at the beginning, we don't need to stock them in the binary image, thus reducing the size of the executable.

In RAM (or virtual memory, where your program will run), with those flags you mentioned, the variables in bss are removed too.

You can check this with a simple program :
If you are using linux, go to /tmp and write a hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int var1 = 0;

int var2 = 2;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

now, type:

```
make hello

objdump --sym hello | less
```

You will see that var1 and var2 are there.

now type :

```
rm hello && make hello CFLAGS="-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections"

objdump --sym hello | less
```

You will not find them anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I use physical memory on embedded system, the unused .bss symbol would be in ram.

Comment: The unused bss will be removed with those flags.
In the example that I gave, the var1 is in the bss and it is removed when you compile with those flags.